# Generate Silverlight service proxies with same namespace

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I need to generate service proxies for multiple WCF services within the same namespace, which is not possible when using the Add Service Reference function of Visual Studio.

How can I do this in an automated way? I've considered using [SLsvcUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197958%28VS.95%29.aspx), but that would require that I make sure that I have my WCF services accessible, and, assuming I'm using the ASP.NET Development Server, I'd need to manually check the URL.

Ideally, I'd have some way of specifying an assembly, a service type, the configuration (web|app.config) and a target namespace, and then my code would be generated. Any Ideas?

### Edit

To clarify, I'm trying to solve the same problem that is outlined in this connect issue: 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/426791/adding-multiple-service-references-from-same-application-should-not-require-multiple-namespaces

I want a no-hassle, automated way to generate service proxies within a single namespace. It's unacceptable for me to have to specify a unique namespace for each service reference. Using SLsvcUtil is an option, but it requires that I have my service up-and-running so it can read the metadata - which is a problem because I don't always have the latest version of the service running at any given point in time.

The "Add Service Reference" functionality in VS handles this well - it automatically hosts the service just long enough to grab the metadata, and then generates the service contract interfaces and proxies. Once again, it requires that each service be code-gen'd in its own, unique namespace, which I don't want.

All I need is a way to generate the service proxies with a single, shared namespace, without having to go through the hassle of manually hosting and firing up an instance of my services. Ideally, I'd just double click a script file.

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do is to inform a composite namespace. When the "Add Service Reference" dialog pops up, I put in the namespace something like `Services.ServiceA` or `Services.ServiceB`. Then all service namespaces share the common root `Services.*`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you're concerned because the way Add Service Reference functions, the ServiceContract interfaces are not exactly the same as the ones you define in your source assembly.

The only real difference is that the ServiceContract interface that Add Service Reference generates for SL has asynchronous operations defined (since SL doesn't support synchronous WCF calls). The rest of it (the `XXXClient : ClientBase` class) can be completely bypassed if you just use the `ChannelFactory<TServiceContractInterface>` directly.

I personally ended up sharing the synchronous ServiceContract interface, but creating a service contract with asynchronous operations using a System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder. Then using a custom ChannelFactory, I created a wrapper around the dynamically generated asynchronous ServiceContract interface.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is that when you use "Add Service Reference..." in a Silverlight project, it requires that each service contract interface be generated in *it's own namespace*, which means that I can't have some common namespace like `MyProject.Services`, it has to be `MyProject.ServiceA.IAService`, `MyProject.ServiceB.IBService`, etc. This is the same problem as outlined here: http://bit.ly/f04JtG

Comment: Here's the full link to the aforementioned connect issue (because bit.ly bitches about phishing...): http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/426791/adding-multiple-service-references-from-same-application-should-not-require-multiple-namespaces